RediSearchAsyncCommands complains "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" when executing search command
I adapt spring-redisearch as search framework on redis, when I doing search, it throws following exception, the AbstractMap having problem is Collections$.EmptyMap
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at io.lettuce.core.output.MapOutput.set(MapOutput.java:56)
    at com.redislabs.lettusearch.output.SearchOutput.set(SearchOutput.java:60)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.safeSetSingle(RedisStateMachine.java:826)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.handleSingle(RedisStateMachine.java:358)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine$State$Type.handle(RedisStateMachine.java:206)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.doDecode(RedisStateMachine.java:334)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.decode(RedisStateMachine.java:295)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:841)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode0(CommandHandler.java:792)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:775)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:658)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

following is code snippet, during debug, I can see search result reside in RedisFuture, but throws above exception when calling get().
RediSearchAsyncCommands<String, String> command= rediSearchConnection.async();
Object result = command.search("index:name", "@name:searchTerm", options).get();
if (result instanceof SearchResults) {
    SearchResults<String, String> searchResults = (SearchResults<String, String>) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchResults.getCount(); i++) {
        Document<String, String> document = searchResults.get(i);
        logger.info(document.get("primaryKey"));
    }
}

Pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.redislabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-redisearch</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

I tried to do it in sync way， tried different versions of spring-boot and spring-redisearch, but still doesn't work, I can't figure out what's going on, any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer it myself, my sping-redisearch version is not compatible with the one of redis-stack, redisearch state machine doesn't work properly and made wrong method call. Changed to 6.2.6 works
